# R: Generate a Seasonal ARIMA time-series model using parameters of existing data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a count time series data which I'm able to use to determine the parameters of the underlying stochastic process. For example say I have a SARIMA (p,d,q)(P,D,Q)[S] seasonal ARIMA model.

How do I use this to generate a new count time series data set?

Being even more specific: a SARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,0)[12] - how can I generate a time series for a 10 year period for each month? (i.e., 120 points to estimate the number of 'counts'.)

Comment: `arima.sim()` can be used to simulate data, though I'm not seeing in the help file that it supports seasonal components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `simulate.Arima()` from the `forecast` package. It handles seasonal ARIMA models whereas `arima.sim()` does not.

However, ARIMA models are not suitable for count time series as they assume the process is defined on the whole real line.

Comment: thanks - I will look into the assumption beding the ARIMA models.

Comment: I don't really understand the documentation. What is the `x` in `nsim=length(object$x)` in the Arguments? My 'object' is a ts object.

Comment: nsim is the length of the simulated time series. The default value is the length of the original time series used to construct the model.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I did not create a Arima object.

Comment: Could you specify a full example how to simulate a seasonal arima with simulate.Arima command? I am unable to figure out how to specify the coefficients.